# DateTime format usage in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, time, timezone

I have following date time format

```
TimeZoneDetails.TimeZoneInstance ="Australia/Perth"
DateTime Today = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow,TimeZoneDetails.TimeZoneInstance);
```

Does today variable store the date based on timezone?

```
string date = "2020-03-19";
DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

What is the timezone of `startdate` variable?

```
DateTime enddate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(startdate, TimeZoneDetails.TimeZoneInstance);
```

Will `enddate` variable converted to UTC time?

Comment: Did you check the [DateTime.Kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind) property? A `DateTime` does not "have" a timezone. A `DateTime` is basically an Int64 value counting the ticks since `DateTime.MinValue` with two bits reserved for this `DateTimeKind` property. But that only tells, if the `DateTime` is meant to be "Local", "UTC" or "Unspecified". No additional timezone information is stored there.

Comment: @ Corak yap. asper my knowledge is not possible to set  DateTime.Kind to Date time.Parse

Comment: You can [specify kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.specifykind). But even then, "local" is just "local", not a _specific_ timezone.

Comment: @Corak .we can't specify time zone using DateTime.Kind

Comment: yap you are right

Comment: Yes, because `DateTime` _does not have_ time zone information stored.

Comment: is it Datetime  converted the value to local time zone ?

Comment: which one is default for DateTimeKind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- `"Australia/Perth"` is an IANA time zone identifier.  It will work with .NET on Linux or Mac OSX, but on Windows you'd have to use `"W. Australia Standard Time"` instead.  Alternatively, you could use my [TimeZoneConverter library](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) to work with either form of identifier on any platform.
- In your code:

  > ```
  > TimeZoneDetails.TimeZoneInstance ="Australia/Perth"
  > ```

  This isn't generally valid.  Given the usage in the rest of your code, your `TimeZoneInstance` would have to be a `TimeZoneInfo` object. You can't assign a string in that way.  You'd have to use a function like `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`, or `TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo` from TimeZoneConverter, or a similar function in your own code.  (Also you're missing a semicolon.)
- In your code:

  > ```
  > string date = "2020-03-19";
  > DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse(date);
  > ```

  You asked what the time zone is in the `startdate` variable.  That's a `DateTime`, which does not store time zone or offset information.  It only has a `.Kind` property, which is of type `DateTimeKind`.  In your example, it will be `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  Also note the time will be set to `00:00:00.0000000`.

  You can read more about this in the documentation, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind#System_DateTime_Kind) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind).
- In your code:

  > ```
  > DateTime enddate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(startdate, TimeZoneDetails.TimeZoneInstance);
  > ```

  Yes, that will correctly convert the `DateTime` from the time zone given to UTC.  Because `startdate.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, the value is treated as belonging to the time zone specified.  The resulting value will have `enddate.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc`.

  You can read more in the documentation, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimetoutc#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTimeToUtc_System_DateTime_System_TimeZoneInfo_).
- In comments you asked:

  > which one is default for `DateTimeKind`?

  That depends on which method you call to create the `DateTime`, and what values you pass in.  In your case, because you call `DateTime.Parse` and pass a string that contains no time zone offset information, the resulting value has `.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  You can read more about the behavior of `DateTime.Parse` in the remarks section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_).  Other methods and constructors behave similarly, but you should check the documentation for each, or validate the results yourself.  You may find conversion errors if you, for example, think a `DateTime` has `Unspecified` kind, but it actually has `Local` kind due to how you obtain it.